# OKHTTP3 SocketTimeOut only on Specific Call

Tags: android, okhttp, kindle-fire, okio

I have a mobile app that makes roughly 15 API calls to our REST API. Most of these are GET, POST, PUT and contain small to medium sized JSON body/response. We are using OKHTTP3 3.8.1 .

We have one call that we make to API Gateway->Lambda that contains a slightly larger JSON body (less than 500kb).

The one call that goes out to API Gateway fails fairly consistently. However, it only fails when we test on an Amazon Kindle Fire 7. The call works on Kindle Fire 8, as well as all other Android phone/tablets we have tested.

I have created another app to test this call using copy pasted code. In the test app, the call does not fail. However, that app is not making our other calls and is not using BLE or any other resources.

When the call fails, the server (API Gateway) does not receive the request at all (Nothing is Logged). So I believe the issue is getting the data off the tablet.

This is the stack trace we get when it fails.

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:37)
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:237)
 at okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:139)
 at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:237)
 at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:345)
 at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:217)
 at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:211)
 at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http1Codec.java:189)
 at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:75)
 at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
 at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
 at com.company.app.helpers.http.HTTPHelpers$LoggingInterceptor.intercept(HTTPHelpers.java:202)
 at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
 at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
 at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
 at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
 at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
 at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
 at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
 at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
 at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
 at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120)
 at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
 at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
 at com.company.app.helpers.http.HTTPHelpers$HeaderInterceptor.intercept(HTTPHelpers.java:225)
 at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
 at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
 at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:185)
 at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:135)
 at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

If anyone has any ideas on why we are getting this error and what could possibly be the fix, I would greatly appreciate any advice!

Edit - We have tried increasing the timeout and the call still does not leave the tablet. We have confirmed the call does not leave the tablet using a proxy.

Additionally, it appears the issue is tied to utilizing BLE at the same time as HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing your timeout in okhttp

```
new OkHttpClient.Builder() .connectTimeout(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS).readTimeout(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS) .writeTimeout(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
```

Comment: We have increased the timeout and the call does not leave the tablet still.